# How to pass function arguments to another function?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function A(a,b){
return /*something*/
}

function B(){
var a = /*a from function A*/
var b = /*b from function A*/
return /*something*/ 
}
```

How to pass the arguments a and b from function A to function B ?

Comment: please clarify. doesnt make much sense right now. you never call B

Answer (score 0):

why not something simple like this :

```
function A(a,b){
  a++;b++;// an example
  return [a,b];
}

function B(){
  var val = A(4,5);// a test value
  var a = val[0];
  var b = val[1];
  Logger.log(a+'  '+b);
  return /*something*/ 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make 2 global varialbes.

```
var c = 0
var d = 0
function A(a,b){
    c = a
    d = b
    return /*something*/
}
```

Be aware that this will not work if you are calling funtion A multiple times, before calling funtion B. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: **Exception: Invalid argument: c**
I guess Google Apps Script won't allow it.